# How to install and run beamer theme on MiKTeX 2.9

Tags: beamer, xetex, luatex, texmaker, windows

I've been trying to use this beamer theme: https://github.com/ppletscher/beamerthemezurich/.
When I try to compile the sample .tex file included it gives me an error that reads:

```
! Fatal fontspec error: "cannot-use-pdftex"
!
! The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaTeX to function.
!
! You must change your typesetting engine to, e.g., "xelatex" or "lualatex"
! instead of plain "latex" or "pdflatex".
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
!
! For immediate help type H <return>.
!...............................................
l.38 }
|'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
| This is a fatal error: LaTeX will abort
|...............................................
) ) ) )
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 20 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 20 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 6 was incomplete)
(\end occurred when \ifx on line 6 was incomplete)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
22086 strings out of 493921
418411 string characters out of 3147276
482941 words of memory out of 3000000
24934 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
5018 words of font info for 17 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
841 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
61i,1n,70p,412b,277s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
9 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
31 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

How can I solve this problem? I'm still fairly new to LaTeX. I have tried switching the typesetting engine to XeTeX and LuaLaTeX on TeXMaker 4.3

Comment: What happened when you switched engines? This problem would have been fixed -- did you run into another?

Comment: It kept on giving me the same error.

Comment: Are you sure TeXmaker was actually switching the engines?  Can you edit-in exactly *how* you were compiling?  You may be making a setting, but not actually applying it.  (That's the trouble with some interfaces -- you can never be sure of when settings are actually *set*.)

Comment: I did what you said and it did help somewhat, now the compiler claims "! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
!
! The font "Gill Sans" cannot be found.
!
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.

Comment: You will have to download `Gill Sans` (and any other fonts it wants) [from the web](http://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/gill-sans) or configure the theme to use a different font.  `\setmainfont` and `\setsansfont` should be sufficient; see [these lines](https://github.com/ppletscher/beamerthemezurich/blob/e6b55d92e97ad0221c0554771ea3e9e70ac895a8/beamerfontthemeZurich.sty#L30).  Basically, replace instances of `Gill Sans` with a font you have installed :)

Comment: If you wish, you may ask a different question specifically asking how to do this for this theme specifically.  If you do this, though, you should post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so others can more easily help.

Comment: Thank you @SeanAllred, I got it working! I really appreciate it! I messed around with the the source file. Thank you!